# How to Delete a Junction by Using Command Prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, junction

I believe in Windows Vista, we could use **`linkd`** command. However, I cannot find this command in Windows 7. I know I can use Windows Explorer and delete the junction, but I wonder if this can be done in Command Prompt.

I can use `mklink` command to create a junction from a Command Prompt, so, what is the opposite of it (something like `linkd`)?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Delete junctions with **`rmdir`** ([`rd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd)). Works in all Windows versions.

Comment: @gravity, thanks! **rd** works while **del** does not.

Comment: Thanks :) This works fine. I didn't want to do it in Explorer as it may delete the target stuff too.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. I had to do the following in a console with administrator privileges first: fsutil reparsepoint delete C:\Path\To\Junction

Comment: This does not work in Powershell - it will follow the junction and delete all files. Use cmd /c "rmdir mydir".

Comment: @BrianLow: Wat.

Comment: @grawity Seems to for me: https://gist.github.com/brianlow/0d5d2070c87c378454d7

Comment: rmdir tells dir is not empty for junction

Comment: when the linked directory is invalid `rd` returned an error but `del` worked

Comment: `rd` and `rmdir` are aliases to `Remove-Item` in PowerShell, so it's no wonder. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060418/476371) may be of relevance ...

Answer (score 33):

In my experience [`fsutil reparsepoint`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-reparsepoint) will take care of some cases where `rmdir` gives **Access Denied**.

```
fsutil reparsepoint delete <<PATH>>
```

Comment: I had a junction point that was giving access denied if I used rmdir. Using this method, the junction point becomes a regular folder with read-only attribute. attrib -R and rmdir finally finished the job.

Comment: Absolute legend! was getting "Unspecified Error" or Access Denied" when attempting to delete a stale WindowsApps directory in explorer after much messing around with rmdir, del, and a few other attempts I realised a few contained directories were actually junctions despite having ownership, granting permissions, removing read only attribute, nothing wanted to remove them however your answer worked! Thank you :)

Comment: This works but it will leave the actual mount point dir behind, as an empty dir. The latter has to be deleted separately.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `-d` flag on `junction`  (`junction -d ...`)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction

- [junction.exe](http://live.sysinternals.com/junction.exe)
- [junction64.exe](http://live.sysinternals.com/junction64.exe)

Comment: You had to mention that `junction` is a separate utility that needs to be downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
linkd source /D
```

will delete the junction point (the link) without deleting on destination

Comment: Read the question. This command doesn't exist in Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into pretty severe issue where none of the above worked (fsutil or sysinternal junction command) because I had moved WindowsApps folder to different drive and then tried to use that drive on another computer. Once junctions don't have valid pointer, it seems they get impossible to be deleted. One thing that seems to worked was using WSL (type command `bash`) from elevated Windows terminal and then do `sudo rm -rf \mnt\e\WindowsApps\`. You can also try to turn off Gaming Services in Services if you keep getting Access Denied (alternatively, login to console at startup). Another useful app towards this task is [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/) which allows to mark files to be deleted at startup.